# Unknown class _TtC8Material20BarLineChartViewBase in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, uiview, charts

I have used a xib file which contains Single UIView and in that UIView i have applied the class and added 3 UIView from which one of them is BarLineChartViewBase . I have Created the outlets for them and i am using the outlets in another class which is UIViewController in which i have used ScrollView and PageControl

```
import UIKit
import Charts
//this is the UIView in the XIB file    
class Home: UIView {

      @IBOutlet weak var barGraphView: BarLineChartViewBase!
      @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
        /*
        // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
        // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
        override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            // Drawing code
        }
        */

}
import UIKit
import Charts

class HomeViewController: UIViewController , UIScrollViewDelegate{
  let featureOne = ["name":"Date-Time","graph":"BarGraph","total":"Battery Discharge"]
  let featureTwo = ["name":"Time-Date","graph":"LineGraph","total":"Battery Charge"]
  let featureThree = ["name":"Calender","graph":"Pie Chart","total":"Input Voltage"]
  var featureArray = [Dictionary<String,String>]()
  @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
  @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
  var months:[String]!
  var unitsSold:[Double]!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"]
    unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0]

    menuButton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    featureArray = [featureOne,featureTwo,featureThree]
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width * CGFloat(featureArray.count), height: scrollView.bounds.height)
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    loadData()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(HomeViewController.loadData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    self.view.insertSubview(scrollView, at: 0)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func loadData(){
    for (index,feature) in featureArray.enumerated(){
      if let featureView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Home", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? Home {
        featureView.nameLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: NSDate() as Date, dateStyle: DateFormatter.Style.none, timeStyle: DateFormatter.Style.medium)
        featureView.barGraphView.noDataText = "No Data" //Unknown class _TtC8Material20BarLineChartViewBase in Interface Builder file.
        featureView.barGraphView.data = setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
        featureView.totalLabel.text = feature["total"]
        scrollView.addSubview(featureView)
        featureView.frame.size.height = scrollView.bounds.height
        featureView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width
        featureView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * self.view.bounds.size.width

      }
    }
  }

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) -> BarChartData {
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
      //      let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
      let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: (values[i]))
      dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    //    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])
    return chartData
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(page)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show how did you set `BarLineChartViewBase` class in xib,  `module` might be missing

Comment: @AnilVarghese i have applied the class to the UIView in the xib file

Comment: can you post a a screenshot?

Comment: Added the screenshot and i have solved it , the module should be Charts but it was Material so changed it and solved it.